# Escaping a password using mysqldump console

Tags: passwords, escape-characters, mysqldump

I am running a mysqldump via a bash script and have encountered a problem with a password that contains special characters.

```
mysqldump -hlocalhost -uUSERNAME -pPA$$W0RD DATABASE | 
                                gzip > /home/USERNAME/backups-mysql/BACKUP.gz
```

How do I escape the password?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

I found the answer.  You have to quote the password, like this:

```
mysql -u root -p'PASSWORD'
```

You must do this if the password has any of the following characters: `* ? [ < > & ; ! | $ ( )`

Comment: Do you know how to escape apostrophes within the password?

Comment: @SteveMayne i think its just a backslash before it

Comment: parenthesis also need to be in quotes.

Comment: On Windows I found I had to use double quotes. Single quotes did not work. (MySQL 5.6)

Comment: blanks in the password also require the ' '

Answer (score 13):

when you use the quotes, make sure there is no space :
between `-p` and `'PASSWORD'`  or
between `--password=` and `'PASSWORD'`

correct:
`mysql -u root -p'PASSWORD'`
`mysql -u root --password='PASSWORD'`

does not work:
`mysql -u root -p 'PASSWORD'` 
`mysql -u root --password = 'PASSWORD'`

you can also define a variable and then use it for the command (still with no spaces in between)
`MSQLPWD='PASSWORD'`
`mysql -u root -p$MSQLPWD`

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your shell. Are you using Microsoft Windows or Linux? If you are using Linux/BASH then it is likely that $$ is being interpreted as your current process ID. Have you tried putting a backslash in front of each dollar sign? e.g.

```
mysqldump \
  -hlocalhost \
  -uUSERNAME \
  -pPA\$\$W0RD \
  DATABASE \
| gzip -c \
> /home/USERNAME/backups-mysql/BACKUP.gz
```

Note that gzip probably requires the "-c" option if you want to compress to STDOUT.

Comment: The password I am using is not PA$$W0RD but I used this as an example.  The actual password I am using has an ampersand and this is what is causing the problem.  I used the backslash as you suggested but it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Try backslashing (`\`) those special chars.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using mysqldump.exe on windows you should use the double quotes, not single quotes like

```
mysqldump.exe --user=roo --password="WE&&^6HJg&^7" .....
```